# How to do conditional formatting against a range of times

Tags: excel

I have a lunch rota which has the names and the times people are going on lunch. I'm trying to make it possible to add a more visual approach to when people lunches are. So that we can see who the number of people available between times.

The idea was to have a list of times in 30-minute increments from 9:00 to 17:00 and with the use of conditional formatting the colour would change gradually depending on the availability.

The complexity comes from certain people either having either 30 or 1-hour breaks. Any idea of how this could be done will be a great help this is to limit people having lunches at the same time and causing issues.

Thanks in advance.

Edit - I've added a link with a screenshot of the concept I'll like to achieve. I have 25 users total across 3 groups and if there's less then 2 available per half hour slot. I'll like the colour to change to orange and then if 1 or less change to red. (Not all 25 users are always in).

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqERk.png]

Comment: It would be best to show sample input and output to help understand what you need

Comment: @AlexP Good idea i'll add it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have assumed you want to count the number of users on their lunch break in each time slot. If you need something more you can use my answer as a starting point, e.g. If you want the number of users excluding those on lunch break.

1: Add a new column 'End', D2 =B2+C2, and paste this for each user

2: Add formula in Covered column:

```
=COUNTIFS(B$2:B$31,"<=" & F2,D$2:D$31,">" & F2)
```

This formula counts the number of users who are at lunch in that time slot.

Copy this down column G to end at 17:00. The F2 will change to F3 so it is the right time slot, while the users' start and end time ranges will stay constant, because of the $.

3: Apply conditional formatting as needed to column G.

[image: Picture]

Comment: Hi, Thanks for this i will give it a try and update this Question.

Comment: Exactly right. The CountIf's function I've not heard of it before. But will look into it going forward.

Thanks